# Android studio 3.6.1 build issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.6

I have just updated android studio **3.6.1**. after this update, I updated all plugins. Now Gradle syncing is failed. Please check the below errors.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process C:\user\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes
Error while dexing.
```

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes I tried clean project, invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: did you try to delete your build folder?

Comment: yes I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: The issue is resolved after updating the project-level build Gradle.    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.7.23-dev' in dependencies  and  maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        } in repositories.

Comment: related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274052/android-studio-problem-with-compiling-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-becaus) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547695/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-run-the-project-wit)

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar problem for a specific project after upgrading to android studio 3.6.1. I tried a couple of things but what worked for me was removing the following line top-level build file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.5.70'
```

Comment: The issue is resolved after updating the project-level build Gradle.` classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.7.23-dev' ` in dependencies and `maven { url 'storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw' } ` in repositories.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get the error "Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools:r8:1.7.23-dev"