# Why do I get “file is used by another process” errors when I run the project within Android Studio 3.6.1?

Tags: android

I encounter this error after running the second time the project.

> ...\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

So far **Clean project** works once, restart the Android Studio works once and the last resort is to restart the pc(running windows 10).

Open to suggestions!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I close the studio and delete the file R.jar from the path and restarting the studio. I din't find any perfect solution for this. Big headache is my project usally takes 5 mints to complete gradle sync so deleting file and restarting the studio takes 10 mints and I am facing this  issue 2-3 times per day.

Comment: related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490068/android-studio-3-6-1-build-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274052/android-studio-problem-with-compiling-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-becaus)

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490068/android-studio-3-6-1-build-issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some workarounds can be found here [Error: Execution failed for task ':app:clean'. Unable to delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914499/error-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file)

When this happens, I use `taskkill /im java.exe /f` in cmd (windows 10). It kills all java processes and releases that file. This is not the best solution, but it's way faster to click on `.bat` file instead of invalidating the whole cache|restart|clean|etc.

I switched from `OpenJDK` to `Oracle JDK`, not sure if this will work with `OpenJDK`.

---

Another workaround is to stop using gradle's daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

> Disabling the Daemon
>
> You can disable the Daemon for a specific build using the `--no-daemon` argument, or disable it for a specific project by explicitly setting `org.gradle.daemon=false` in the project's `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: It is working fine for me, Thx lot's

Answer (score 4):

Manually delete the R.jar file in the file explorer then press rebuild.

The system (*Android Studio Gradle or another debug process*) might be using it automatically even when you haven't asked it to build and **the (automatic) process blocks** your second build process from using it.

Let me know if this works, apparently, Android Studio 4.0.1 has similar problems.