# App build failing after Android Studio 4 update

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, r.java-file, build-error

Shows the following error- C:\Users\shubh\AndroidStudioProjects\BitsandPizzas\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Builds successfully one time and fails the next. Was working when using studio3.6 but this came up after studio4 update

Answer (score 0):

First Do This:
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. -> Invalidate/ Restart

if that not work, try with this solution:

[Why do I get “file is used by another process” errors when I run the project within Android Studio 3.6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547695/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-run-the-project-wit)