# Android Studio problem with compiling "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: android, compilation

I know this question has been asked before, but there wasn't a satisfactory answer, and the last post was three years ago.
I am using android studio 3.6.2 in windows 10. Every time I try to compile my program I get the error
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Now I know what is causing the error. The R.jar file that was previously compiled cannot be deleted because android studio is locking the file.
It is in a folder \app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug

Now to get around the problem I have been closing down android studio. Then deleting the R.jar, then restarting android studio and then compiling.
This process takes a good few minutes and I have to do it every time. Imagine how long it takes to write a program when you have to do this every time.

When this was asked on stack overflow previously suggestions were to Invalid caches / restart, but that is no quicker than what I did above, and only works once.
Also tried Clean Project, but that has no effect.

I have used many compilers over the years like visual studio, codeblocks etc but this kind of thing never happened before, so why is android studio so bad?
Has anyone found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: So you can't run gradle commands like `clean`?

Comment: No idea how to run a gradle command. I just click the green triangle at the top of Android Studio to compile

Comment: Try building and deploying your app via the commandline with gradle. I'm not entirely sure how to execute the gradle wrapper on windows, but on Linux you'd run `./gradlew clean` or `./gradlew build` etc. from the project directory. It will probably look similar.

Comment: related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490068/android-studio-3-6-1-build-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547695/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-run-the-project-wit)

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490068/android-studio-3-6-1-build-issue

Answer (score 3):

[[image: Remove Build]][[image: Go to Edit Configurations]]

Go to Edit Configurations check that you are not building before each launch. Remove "Build"

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem in Android Studio 4.x in Windows 10. Simply using "Restart and Invalidate" does not work for me. Sometimes, deleting the `build` folder will work but I cannot build the project more than once. Here is my solution:

### Check Java Runtime Version Used by Gradle and System Default

Having multiple daemons may cause problems as described in documentation from [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html). To solve this problem,

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Find the JDK location used in your project (File > Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location)
3. Open a command prompt. Let $ANDROID_JDK be the path you found in Step 2. Type `$ANDROID_JDK/bin/java.exe --version` to find out the Java version.
4. Type `java.exe --version` to find out the default Java version used by the system.
5. Compare if the version information from Step 3 and Step 4 are the same.

### Build with `app` Configuration

Empty Composable Activity template will create two build configurations.
You should change the build configuration to `app` as shown in the figure below. This solves my problem.

[image: build configuration]

### Proper Launching Procedure

As illustrated in Bilal Aslam's solution, we can edit the build configurations (Run > Edit Configurations). After selecting `Compose Preview > Default Preview`, you will see `Build` then `Gradle-aware Make` in the `Before launch` panel. Remove `Build` should be able to solve the problem. The side-effects are unclear.