# Android Studio: R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After a new installation of Android Studio 3.6.3 (portable). When I try to build and run my project, I keep getting

> app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar:
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

Not sure what it wants from me. I run Android Studio "as administrator" and even closing the project and reopening it, the first time it runs, the second time I get the error.

I tried invalidate caches and restart, I tried deleting folders under app/build but it seems to come back. What am I missing?

Thanks

**Update:**

When trying to clean the project, I get the following

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\portable\android-studio\projects\appm\app\build'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - C:\Users\name\Downloads\portable\android-studio\projects\appm\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar
    - C:\Users\name\Downloads\portable\android-studio\projects\appm\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug
    - C:\Users\name\Downloads\portable\android-studio\projects\appm\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar
    - C:\Users\name\Downloads\portable\android-studio\projects\appm\app\build\intermediates
```

If I wait for several minutes, for example, the time it took me to update this question, then it works again...

**update:**
Updated to Android Studio 4 and the same problem occurs.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274052/android-studio-problem-with-compiling-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-becaus/65446143#65446143

Answer (score 44):

Try

```
taskkill /im java.exe /f
```

in cmd (windows 10)

Answer (score 29):

I encountered the same problem but on Android Studio Arctic Fox while working on a Jet Compose project.

I simply changed the run configuration and the build error was resolved.
[image]

Change `DefaultPreview` to `app` and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

It's an internal bug in AS, I reported it as a bug, you can follow up here

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167701947

Answer (score 5):

Killing the "*OpenJDK Platform binary*" process from Task manager worked great for me.
Thanks to Abed Murad, which I saw on his link. (I have no reputation to cast a vote yet - my bad!)

> It's an internal bug in AS, I reported it as a bug, you can follow up here
> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167701947

I used to try to delete the file **R.jar** on **...\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug** and when it's locked, I had to close Android Studio then delete **R.jar** before reopening the Android Studio.
Is it (*killing the "OpenJDK Platform binary"*) the best solution? I don't know, however, it's what I got for now. Once I get a better one, I'll update it.
 Luck there guys!

Comment: Doesn't help in >90% of cases. Most times the OpenJDK process doesn't even exist and the file is still locked. Other times it does exist, but after killing it the lock is still present. In the remaining very few cases it frees the lock successfully.

Answer (score 4):

stop running app ,then open any of the xml layout ,wait it load complete, it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm buddy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removiong all `*.xml` files from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\workspace`

I figured it out from [this google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167701947).

Comment: Yes This is working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue all I did remove R.jar and re build my project.

Answer (score 0):

did all the solutions and nothing work for me.
i noticed that i can apply change [image: Ctrl + F10] on java file, but when i change something in XML files this error occurs.
All I can do is shut down Android Studio, manually delete R.jar, then reopen Android Studio, which turned out to be really annoying

not sure what went wrong in here

Answer (score 0):

Migration from kapt to ksp solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a react native project and was using AS to debug my native android code. I had both VS Code AND AS open at the same time and I got this error in AS. When I closed VS Code and ran `taskkill /im java.exe /f` in CMD (thanks @dreinoso), I was able to run the app in AS.

Doing this solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Invalidate cache and restart solved my problem