# Android Studio : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Error : **The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**

**Details :**
I have just downloaded android studio 2020.3.1 Beta 1 (Arctic Fox). I have created new Android studio project for Jetpack compose. Now the scenario is, i have 1 emulator running and android studio has its built-in compose preview. Whenever i try to build app i got this error. I have tried many solutions including invalidating cache restart and few other solutions but none of them seems to be working.
P.S : I have also tried by deleting build folder.
This seems to be specific error in Android studio with compose addition.

I am attaching error screenshot.

[image: Error keeps coming even after invalidating cache]

Answer (score 4):

It's not in jetpack compose context, but works also perfectly fine:
[Android Studio: R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082922/android-studio-r-jar-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-us)

Just copy, paste the following in your Terminal:

```
taskkill /im java.exe /f
```

Comment: This works great. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Compose world you can also try the following:

Check if your run configuration is **Default Preview**
[image]

If so change to **App**

[image]

This should resolve this build error.

```
\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```